# 12.10 64 bit hangs on install

Tags: installation, 12.10

I have tried installing 12.10 now 5 times with no luck. Every time it hangs up at the new features screen of the install. I've tried burning slow. Tried a cd and a DVD. On a clean HDD and tried overwriting a vista HDD. Please help as I need this for school. 
Thank you
Mike

Comment: Please add to your question the specifications of your PC (processor, ram, video card type) to help you.

Comment: This question needs more information. As To Do stated you need to at least list your basic hardware.

Comment: Could be a dupe of the bug where the ubiquity screensaver crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use a Pen drive. Download [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and set up the installer on your pendrive . Boot from pendrive by pressing F8 or whatver key your pc selects the boot mechanism . In my experience booting from Pendrive is much beeter than on DVD. Hope you find this usefull